# Push is not a function array population

Tags: javascript

I want have an array structured as follow:

```
var myMap = {id: ['0', '1'], name:['Op', 'Op2']}
```

Now `Op` and `Op2` is taken by a `$.each` like this:

```
var myMap = {};
var count = 0
$.each(GlobalVariables.availableProviders, function(indexProvider, provider) 
    {
        myMap.push({
            id: count,
            name: provider['first_name']
        });

        count ++;
    });
```

But on `push` the console display this error:

> myMap.push is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `myMap` is an object, you cannot use `push` on an object

Comment: You're right, there's a way to fix this?

Comment: Use `myMap` as array of objects, `var myMap = [{id: ['0', '1'], name:['Op', 'Op2']}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your `var myMap = {};` is a object.
Object dosnt have a *push* method indstead of *Array.prototype*
Simple example how to do it

```
var myMap = {
  id: [],
  name: []
}

myMap.id.push(/* value for id */);
myMap.id.name(/* name */);
```

Answer (score 2):

`myMap` is an object, not an array.

It looks like it should be an array and structured:

```
var myMap = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Op' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Op2' }
];
```

Comment: I need to insert id and name in the each as a pus

Comment: @Jss — So make the change I suggested in the answer.

Comment: nope myMap is an empty variable I just can declare it like var myMap= [], but I've the same problem

Comment: Declaring it as `[]` will also fix it (assuming everything about the rest of the question is also unchanged), since that will also make it an array.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `myMap` is an object not an array.

Change

```
var myMap = {id: ['0', '1'], name:['Op', 'Op2']}
```

to

```
var myMap = [{id: ['0', '1'], name:['Op', 'Op2']}]
```

Comment: I need to insert id and name in the each as a push

Comment: yes you can do that after you do the changes I mentioned.

Comment: but myMap is an empy variable... I doesn't have any value at the initialization, I valorize it in the $.each

Comment: then initialise it before the loop like this: var myMap = [];

Answer (score 0):

The straight solution for your problem would be:

```
myMap.id.push(count);
myMap.name.push(provider['first_name']);
```

... So that `myMap` will still contain the values like this:

```
{id: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'... ], name:['Op', 'Op2', 'Op3', 'Op4', 'Op5'...]}
```

But I do not recommend you this structure. If `id` and `name` shall be stored simultaneously, it is recommended that they be linked together. For example: If `id` values are always unique integers, you could make `myMap` an *array*:

```
var myMap[0]='Op';
var myMap[1]='Op2';
var myMap[2]='Op3';
var myMap[3]='Op4';
...
```